# Accessing variable from expect script(TCL) in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, tcl, expect

I have a shell script in which i am using a expect script.. In expect script there is a find command..
How to access the output of that find command outside expect script?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show us the code you have made so far.

Answer (score 0):

Expect is no more magic than other languages or tools. Just redirect the output of the Expect script and use shell to parse the result.

```
expect /some/script.exp > /some/file
# e.g.
grep some-pattern /some/file
```